# teradata : select data into variable

Tags: oracle11g, teradata

in oracle we have

decalre 
v_data number ;

begin 
 select max(deptno) into v_data from dept;

end;

do we have this type of advatntage of in terdata like selecting the data from table into a variable

can u give the equivalent code in terdata

Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in Teradata that you need to use a similar approach? Yes, you can mimic this behavior in a stored procedure but you could also accomplish this with a CTE, volatile table, or global temporary table that can be referenced within your SQL statement. If you can expand upon the task at hand we may be able to provide a more complete suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In teradata you can use variables only in stored procedure, you cannot use the variables in Teradata SQl statements which are outside of the stored procedure.

You can load the max value into a temporary table and can access it for your manipulations